# How to find Where a List First Went out of Order in Python

Tags: python, list, function

I'm writing this program at school where my teacher wants us to enter 5 numbers into a list, and if the list of numbers is not in order of least to greatest, it is to say where the list first went out of order.

**My code:**

```
#Function Definititions
def start():
  list = []
  for i in range(0,5):
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    list.append(number)
  flag = 0
  i = 1
  while i < len(list):
      if(list[i] < list[i-1]):
          flag = 1
      i += 1
  if(not flag) :
    print("This list of numbers is true.")
  else:
    print("This list of numbers is false. List became out of order at", )
    list = sorted(list, reverse=False) 
    print("True Version:",list)
  return flag

#Main Program
start1 = start()
```

I wanna say where a list like, for example, 10,4,5,8,10 went out of order first, which would be at list[0] in that particular case. I can't add any shortcut functions already built into Python, and the part where my code says  **print("This list of numbers is false. List became out of order at", )** is where I wanna add it, which is why I left it blank in my program. Everything else in my program works fine, so it wouldn't matter too much if a solution can't be found, but if anyone does know what to do, I am all ears.

Comment: Where you're setting `flag=1` you can just say that `list[i-1]` is our of order, print it & break the loop.

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name - it overrides the `list` builtin

Comment: @rdas I tried adding `list[i-1]` but it only printed the very last number mentioned, and not the one where the list first went out of order. Also I don't exactly know where to put the `break` statement in the loop. I tried adding it after `print("True Version:",mylist)` but it kept saying it was outside the loop.

Also I changed everything to `mylist` when referring to the list of numbers

Comment: Can you give a few more examples of input and expected output? It is not clear to me why in your example the answer should be index 0 and not index 1... both contribute to the bad comparison, so why should the first be to blame? For instance, what would be the expected return value for `[5,1,6,7,8]`? And what for `[5,1,6,2,7,3]`?

Comment: Well the first index can be the to blame sometimes, like if the list is something like 10, 4, 8, 5, 10. It can also be index 1 if the list is 1, 2, 1, 3, 5. It's whenever the list is no longer from least to greatest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
# Function Definitions
def start():
    my_list = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        my_list.append(number)
    flag = False
    i = 1
    while i < len(my_list):
        if my_list[i] < my_list[i - 1]:
            # found out of order element
            flag = True
            print(f'Out of order at {my_list[i - 1]}')  # print the element
            break  # no need to continue
        i += 1
    if not flag:
        print("This list of numbers is true.")
    return flag


# Main Program
start1 = start()
```